# How to properly transpose X and Y axes using the D3 axis commands?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, axis, axis-labels

**Original code can be found at:** http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/be1a49bc4c4ad4d0f787a8e26ab2718e (refer to the HTML div labeled "**Transitions Axes using a button, with a short delay**")

In the above example, I try to transpose the Y axis to X and the X axis to Y using the following D3 code...

```
function draw70( xAxisData, yAxisData, selectString )
  {

    var flag = true;
    var w = 500;
    var h = 400;
    var marginLeft = 10;
    var marginRight = w - 10;
    var marginTop = 20;
    var marginBottom = h - 20;

    var lineData = [];
    var pt1 = {x: 0, y: 0};
    lineData.push(pt1);
    var pt2 = {x: 0, y: h};
    lineData.push(pt2);
    var pt3 = {x: w, y: h};
    lineData.push(pt3);
    var pt4 = {x: w, y: 0};
    lineData.push(pt4);
    var pt5 = {x: 0, y: 0};
    lineData.push(pt5);

    var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
      .interpolate("linear");

    var canvas = d3.select(selectString).append("svg")
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("width", w)

    // Put a border around the canvas for visual effects
    canvas.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 4)
        .attr("fill", "none");

    // InnerCanvas is the offset canvas, that is offset away
    // from the margins, using the transform/translate for the
    // entire canvas, instead of just for individual axis.
    var innerCanvas = canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(60,10)");

    // Setup y axis : Range is the length of the line
    // NOTE: A value of "1" for rangeRoundBands allows points
    // to be centered over the ordinal text markers
    var yAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(yAxisData).rangeRoundBands([marginBottom-20, marginTop], 1);
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yAxisScale).orient("left");
    var yAxisGroup = innerCanvas.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Setup x axis : Range is the length of the line
    // NOTE: A value of "1" for rangeRoundBands allows points
    // to be centered over the ordinal text markers
    var xAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xAxisData).rangeRoundBands([0, (marginRight-100)], 1);
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xAxisScale).orient("bottom");
    var xAxisGroup = innerCanvas.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,354)")
      .call(xAxis);

    d3.select("#buttonChart70")
      .on("click", function(){

        var color;
        if (flag) {
          //yAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xAxisData).rangeRoundBands([marginBottom-20, marginTop], 1);
          //xAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(yAxisData).rangeRoundBands([0, (marginRight-100)], 1);
          yAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xAxisData).rangeRoundBands([marginTop, marginBottom-20], 1);
          xAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(yAxisData).rangeRoundBands([(marginRight-100), 0], 1);
```

yAxis.orient("bottom");
xAxis.orient("left");
              color = "red";
            } else {
              yAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(yAxisData).rangeRoundBands([marginBottom-20, marginTop], 1);
              xAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xAxisData).rangeRoundBands([0, (marginRight-100)], 1);
yAxis.orient("bottom");
xAxis.orient("left");
              color = "black";
            }

```
        flag = !flag

        // Transitions the Y axis to X value set.
        var yTransitions = innerCanvas.selectAll(".y.axis")
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
            .delay(200)
            .attr("fill", color)
            .attr("transform", function(){
                if (flag){
                  return "transform(0, 354)";
                } else {
                  return "transform(marginTop, marginBottom-20)";
                  //return "transform(marginBottom-20, marginTop)";
                };
              }
            )
          .call(yAxis);

        // Transitions the X axis to Y value set.
        var xTransitions = innerCanvas.selectAll(".x.axis")
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
            .delay(200)
            .attr("fill", color)
            //.attr("transform", "translate(0,354)")
            .attr("transform", function(){
                if (flag){
                  return "transform(marginTop, marginBottom-20)";
                  //return "transform(marginBottom-20, marginTop)";
                } else {
                  return "transform(0, 354)";
                };
              }
            )
          .call(xAxis);

      })
      .on("mouseover", function(){ 
        var thisObject = d3.select(this);
        thisObject.style({"background-color": "DarkGreen"});
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function(){ 
        var thisObject = d3.select(this);
        thisObject.style({"background-color": "#4CAF50"});
      });

  };
```

Upon selecting the button, the axes move but not to the correct locations, nor do they go back to the right locations.  Also the text is reversed after they move.

NOTE: I want to transition, both, the text and the line/path.

What's the right way to do this?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to swap the xAxis for the yAxis, is that right? In that case, you have to do all the changes you want in the scales and the axis and, after applying the changes, transitioning the axis:

```
d3.transition(svg)
    .select(".x.axis")//this class was previously applied
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .call(xAxis);
```

Check this snippet:

```js
var width = 400, height = 400, flag = true;
var svg = d3.select("#svgdiv")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain("ABCDEFGHIJ".split(""))
  .rangeBands([30, width - 20]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 10])
  .range([height - 20, 20]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height-20})`)
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30, 0)")
  .call(yAxis);

//here is the code for transposing the axes:

d3.select("#myButton").on("click", function(){

  if(flag){
    yAxis.orient("bottom");
    xAxis.orient("left");
xScale.domain("ABCDEFGHIJ".split(""))
  .rangeBands([width - 20, 30]);
yScale.domain([0, 10])
  .range([20, height - 20]);
  } else {
    yAxis.orient("left");
    xAxis.orient("bottom");
xScale.domain("ABCDEFGHIJ".split(""))
  .rangeBands([30, width - 20]);

yScale.domain([0, 10])
  .range([height - 20, 20]);
  };
  
  d3.transition(svg)
    .select(".x.axis")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", function(){
      if(flag){
      return "translate(30, 0)"
      } else { return `translate(0,${height-20})`}})
    .call(xAxis);

  d3.transition(svg)
    .select(".y.axis")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("transform", function(){
      if(!flag){
      return "translate(30, 0)"
    } else { return `translate(10,${height-20})`}})
    .call(yAxis);
  
    flag = !flag;
  
});
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #aaa;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">Swap</button>
<div id="svgdiv"></div>
```

Comment: By the way, your axis flips do not re-orient your data accurately.  Numbers and letters are reversed when you transpose.  They should not be reversed.

Comment: @Information Technology, It's just a matter of re-setting the ranges. Check the snippet again.

Comment: Still not working, even after adjusting the ranges.  My example specifically uses an inner canvas that has to be accounted for.  It also explicitly uses longer strings (seasons) for the labels on one axis so that an offset has to be accounted for when those strings transition to the left side.  I don't see these things in the response snippet and I'm wondering if they have anything to do with why it's not working the same way.  NOTE: I updated the original example so you can see (in the last HTML div).

Comment: My snippet is just a general answer, it's not based on your code. Feel free to unaccept my answer and let's hope that someone else provides you a desired answer.